# Javascript onClick function not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Delete Paper </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                    document.write('<?php 
                        session_start();
                        $username = "";
                        $password = "";
                        $server = "localhost";
                        $user = "";
                        $pass = "";
                        $db = "test";
                        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];


                        $conn = new mysqli($server,$user,$pass, $db);
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM questionpapercount where userid='$userid'";
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);

                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            $paper = $row['paperid'];
                            echo "<input type=checkbox name=$paper /> $paper ";
                        }

                        $conn->close();

                     ?> ');
                    function deletequery(){
                        alert('abcd');
                    }
                </script>
            <input type=button value=Delete onclick=deletequery() />
        </body>
    </html>
```

My javascript function is not working properly. If i write onclick a simple alert('abcd'); then it is working fine, but if i write a function instead then it is not working.

Comment: `delete` is a keyword. You cannot use it as identifier. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords . Rename the function. It also seems like you are trying to echo arbitrary HTML into a `<script>` element. That won't work.

Comment: I don't even know what you are trying to do. This file looks like a failed merge to me.

Comment: Trying to execute PHP on client side. Oh... :( thats a bigger issue than JS not working.

Comment: @Sushant: What php is he trying to execute client-side?

Comment: @Felix Kling as you said earlier "It also seems like you are trying to echo arbitrary HTML into a <script> element. That won't work" Then how should i embed php into script ??

Comment: All I'm saying is that any html must be outside of `<script>`.

Comment: @ Cerbrus: actually what i wanted is, my database contains a question paper which contains some questions and upon clicking the button, one by one each question should be displayed. For doing that i initially tried to alert some text by clicking the button n times.

Comment: @FelixKling that's fine, but how to embed php into script?? the way in which i did is correct or not. If not then how??

Answer (score 0):

[`delete` is a operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) in JavaScript, so these lines won't work:

```
function delete(){
    alert('abcd');
}

document.write("<input type=button value=Delete onclick=delete(); />");
```

Rename your function to fix your code. You should also put your HTML attributes in quotes:

```
function deleteHandler(){
    alert('abcd');
}

document.write('<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteHandler();" />');
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete is a keyword, so you can use "del" or another name instead of delete.

Comment: There is no character limit for answers, so there is no need to use textspeak to shorten words. Please use proper English.